# How to move Tomcat's Manager to another port or remove it at all and still use Deploy to container Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, amazon-ec2, deployment

I use: Amazon ec2, Ubuntu 14, Jenkins 2.32.2, Tomcat 8.
Also use "Deploy to container Plugin" in Jenkins which allows me to easily put *.war to the Tomcat. It's working fine, when your application and the Tomcat's Manager work on the same port.

Now I have my website: my-server:8080 and I still have Tomcat manager on my-server:8080/manager. If I just remove directory manager from Tomcat's webapps - *Deploy to container Plugin* stop working and can't put war to the Tomcat.

What I want: move manager to the port 8082. But still want be able to make this during my websit deploying with Jenkins:
[image]

Another words, I want you should not be able to get Tomcat's manager from any path on 8080 (my-server:8080/***).

Maybe I don't need to move Tomcat to another port, but need somehow remove all Manager's pages.

p.s. on the screenshot you see Tomcat 7.x, but it works greate with Tomcat 8 also.